# I am unable to publish and verify my contract on etherscan kovan test network. (Year 2021)

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, contract-verification, timelock

I am trying to publish my contract on kovan testnet but in the compiler output section, I am getting the same error again and again. I tried to do everything which was asked there, but couldn't find a possible solution. Here is my error

```
Compiler debug log:


Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])
 For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions

Compiler Warning(s):

ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> myc:5:1:
  |
5 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> myc:6:1:
  |
6 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> myc:7:1:
  |
7 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    Compiler Version: v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7
Optimization Enabled: True
Runs: 200

ByteCode (what we are looking for):
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{ipfs}64736f6c634300080700330000000000000000000000004eae6def41cc02f2895c400ed7fef679729b07970000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061560228000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

***This link here will redirect to my transaction details :
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x06a045ca30f26c1c494ab895c43e91e69f889ebbf238926ddd604da6ba04ed89***

For reference, I am providing my code as well. A little description about my code: I am making a timelock smart contract where a linear distribution of the token needs to be done after certain conditions are met. For e.g, for some beneficiary addresses, they will get their full amount after 10 months, which means 1/10 amount of token will be mined to them every month so that after 10 they will receive their all tokens. Please have a look at my contract as well. Here it is:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

/**
 * @title TokenVesting
 * @dev A token holder contract that can release its token balance gradually like a
 * typical vesting scheme, with a cliff and vesting period. Optionally revocable by the
 * owner.
 */
contract TokenVesting is Ownable {
    // The vesting schedule is time-based (i.e. using block timestamps as opposed to e.g. block numbers), and is
    // therefore sensitive to timestamp manipulation (which is something miners can do, to a certain degree). Therefore,
    // it is recommended to avoid using short time durations (less than a minute). Typical vesting schemes, with a
    // cliff period of a year and a duration of four years, are safe to use.
    // solhint-disable not-rely-on-time

    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    event TokensReleased(address token, uint256 amount);
    event TokenVestingRevoked(address token);

    // beneficiary of tokens after they are released
    address private _beneficiary;

    // Durations and timestamps are expressed in UNIX time, the same units as block.timestamp.
    uint256 private _cliff;
    uint256 private _start;
    uint256 private _duration;

    bool private _revocable;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _released;
    mapping (address => bool) private _revoked;

    /**
     * @dev Creates a vesting contract that vests its balance of any ERC20 token to the
     * beneficiary, gradually in a linear fashion until start + duration. By then all
     * of the balance will have vested.
     * @param beneficiary address of the beneficiary to whom vested tokens are transferred
     * @param cliffDuration duration in seconds of the cliff in which tokens will begin to vest
     * @param start the time (as Unix time) at which point vesting starts
     * @param duration duration in seconds of the period in which the tokens will vest
     * @param revocable whether the vesting is revocable or not
     */
    constructor (address beneficiary, uint256 start, uint256 cliffDuration, uint256 duration, bool revocable) {
        require(beneficiary != address(0), "TokenVesting: beneficiary is the zero address");
        // solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
        require(cliffDuration <= duration, "TokenVesting: cliff is longer than duration");
        require(duration > 0, "TokenVesting: duration is 0");
        // solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
        require(start.add(duration) > block.timestamp, "TokenVesting: final time is before current time");

        _beneficiary = beneficiary;
        _revocable = revocable;
        _duration = duration;
        _cliff = start.add(cliffDuration);
        _start = start;
    }

    /**
     * @return the beneficiary of the tokens.
     */
    function beneficiary_() public view returns (address) {
        return _beneficiary;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cliff time of the token vesting.
     */
    function cliff_() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _cliff;
    }

    /**
     * @return the start time of the token vesting.
     */
    function start_() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _start;
    }

    /**
     * @return the duration of the token vesting.
     */
    function duration_() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _duration;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the vesting is revocable.
     */
    function revocable_() public view returns (bool) {
        return _revocable;
    }

    /**
     * @return the amount of the token released.
     */
    function released(address token) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _released[token];
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the token is revoked.
     */
    function revoked(address token) public view returns (bool) {
        return _revoked[token];
    }

    /**
     * @notice Transfers vested tokens to beneficiary.
     * @param token ERC20 token which is being vested
     */
    function release(IERC20 token) public {
        uint256 unreleased = _releasableAmount(token);

        require(unreleased > 0, "TokenVesting: no tokens are due");

        _released[address(token)] = _released[address(token)].add(unreleased);

        token.safeTransfer(_beneficiary, unreleased);

        emit TokensReleased(address(token), unreleased);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Allows the owner to revoke the vesting. Tokens already vested
     * remain in the contract, the rest are returned to the owner.
     * @param token ERC20 token which is being vested
     */
    function revoke(IERC20 token) public onlyOwner {
        require(_revocable, "TokenVesting: cannot revoke");
        require(!_revoked[address(token)], "TokenVesting: token already revoked");

        uint256 balance = token.balanceOf(address(this));

        uint256 unreleased = _releasableAmount(token);
        uint256 refund = balance.sub(unreleased);

        _revoked[address(token)] = true;

        token.safeTransfer(owner(), refund);

        emit TokenVestingRevoked(address(token));
    }

    /**
     * @dev Calculates the amount that has already vested but hasn't been released yet.
     * @param token ERC20 token which is being vested
     */
    function _releasableAmount(IERC20 token) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _vestedAmount(token).sub(_released[address(token)]);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Calculates the amount that has already vested.
     * @param token ERC20 token which is being vested
     */
    function _vestedAmount(IERC20 token) private view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 currentBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        uint256 totalBalance = currentBalance.add(_released[address(token)]);

        if (block.timestamp < _cliff) {
            return 0;
        } else if (block.timestamp >= _start.add(_duration) || _revoked[address(token)]) {
            return totalBalance;
        } else {
            return totalBalance.mul(block.timestamp.sub(_start)).div(_duration);
        }
    }
}
```

*Here's a link to a great tutorial, I have found. I tried all the steps that were asked there but still couldn't figure out what was wrong.
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/verify-erc20-token-on-etherscan-that-was-deployed-through-remix-step-by-step-guide/9051*

[image: I have called the constructor and for that, I have deployed the contract using the following values :]

[image: Here are some other photos of the steps]

[image]

Comment: Check out [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol) or, if you're a Hardhat user, [hardhat-etherscan](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/tree/master/packages/hardhat-etherscan).